# Problem with decoding bytes to text and comparison?

Tags: python-3.x

I do not understand why when you open a document in bytes format with the 'open' function and decode it to text, when compared to a variable that contains exactly the same text, python says they are different. But that only happens when the decoded text of the document has line breaks.

example:

```
o = open('New.py','rb')

t = o.read().decode()

x = '''this is a
message for test'''

if t == x:
   print('true')
else:   
   print('false')
```

Although the decoded text 't' and the text of the 'x' are exactly the same, python recognizes them as different and prints false.

I have really tried to find the difference in many ways but I still don't understand how they differ and how I can convert 't' to equal 'x'?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the line breaks are still part of the string (represented as `\n`) even if you don't see it.

```
import binascii

o = open('new.py','rb')
t = o.read().decode()
print(binascii.hexlify(t.encode()))
# b'7468697320697320610a6d65737361676520666f7220746573740a'

x = '''this is a
message for test'''
print(binascii.hexlify(x.encode()))
# b'7468697320697320610a6d65737361676520666f722074657374'
```

Here, `0x0a` at the end of `t` is the byte representation for the new line.

To make them the same, you need to [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) out whitespaces and new lines. Assuming *new.py* looks like this (same as the value for `x`):

```
this is a
message for test
```

Then just do this:

```
o = open('new.py','rb')
t = o.read().decode().strip()
x = '''this is a
message for test'''

if t == x:
   print('true')
else:
   print('false')
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work for me. I already tried it and it didn't work. Do you have any evidence that it worked for you?

Comment: @JhonatanZu Post the contents of New.py. Does New.py also contain a line break between "this is a" and "message for test" ?

Comment: @JhonatanZu I added the *new.py* I used for testing.

Comment: Friend, the text of the document is copied directly from the text of the variable x. They are exactly the same. the only difference is that you save it in py format to be able to decode it. Could you pass me the code of how you got it to return 'true'?  :(

Comment: @JhonatanZu I edited to post the full code. I just added `strip()` to `t`. I also posted the contents of *new.py*. What's unclear to me is the contents of your *new.py* file. What do you mean by "_exactly the same"_? Do you mean the *new.py* also includes the triple quotes (`'''this is a`)? And you don't have to save it as *.py* to read it as binary, you can save it any extension you like.

Comment: Brother, this is all crazy, I swear I copied the exact code you gave me and still prints me 'false'. The damn programming sometimes just makes no sense